# Google FormApp Customisation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I've found lots of examples of coding the deprecated UIapp forms, but very few using the new FormApp class.

What I need is essentially a Grid control that has text boxes for input in place of radio buttons - a table in other words! I'm finding nothing that shows how to set up a table with positioning or a container.

Any suggestions? Preferably I'd love a link to a site that details lots of examples of coding the FormApp as I'm sure this is just the start of a new learning curve.

Thanks!!

Comment: UiApp isn't deprecated, although the GUI Builder tool has been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's FormApp is limited to a fixed number of Item types - just those that are provided by the Forms Service GUI. There is no way to create custom question types or layouts. I suspect the limited ability to customize is the reason you don't find much effort dedicated to creating script examples.

If the data you are collecting requires a different layout than any of the provided "Items", then your only practical option within the Google Apps Script world is to create a custom interface using UiApp or the HtmlService, and record responses into a spreadsheet.

Alternatively, you can submit a feature request on the [Google Apps Script Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/). However, unless the Item already exists in Google Forms (Google Docs), it's unlikely to get any traction from the Google Apps team. (My opinion - I don't speak for Google.)

Comment: I must confess to being a little disorientated with Gadgets & GUI Builder being deprecated but Widgets & uiApp not... n00bs eh? :)

Thanks for the tips again Mogsdad, the uiApp FlexTable is looking interesting, I'll have a play around!