# Add additional and existing script to a Google form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am currently building a Google form to help gauge a competency of our staff members. While building the Google forms you’re given several options when creating your question type, 9 to be exact. (text, paragraph text, multiple-choice, checkboxes, choose from a list, scale, grid, date and time I’m a definite novice when it comes to scripting with a simple understanding of different coding languages which helps me sift through the scripts so please bear with me.

So here’s my question, how would I add a paragraph text to the existing multiple-choice script in the Google form and is it possible?
Here’s a quick test question example we would like to apply to current Google form script:

Question: Do you have experience in handling cash?
Multiple-choice question: Yes or no? (Please explain your answer) <--- this is where I would like to add a script that would allow me to also include a paragraph text just below the multiple question.

I know I can organically create the entire test by adding landing pages as an option after choices made but this means creating a new page for every single question throughout the test with my 40 questions this means building 40 questions with 40 page landings would sound like a massive pain in the ass.

This may be an easy question for somebody out there but I’m sure it’s not going to be for most as I believe Google locks down the default scripting in new forms. My only hope is that the existing Google form that I create essentially belongs to us so re-scripting to add a paragraph text box may not be that big of a deal after all.

Comment: I think multiple-choice questions just lets you display labels. Instead of a yes/no multi-choice, could just make the original question as a text area in the first place and ask user to answer only if yes.

Answer (score 0):

Per this discussion, there is currently no way to modify the action of Google Forms controls:
[Google FormApp Customisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907928/google-formapp-customisation)

If you have the time to get to grips with the UiApp, then you should probably do so, since (as you have discovered) Google Forms are extremely limited in terms of what can be achieved with them.

Additionally, Google handles the data transactions via a background service which makes any adjustments post-contruction liable to cause significant problems with your process. For example, adding a new control 1/2 way down your form will insert a new column at the end of the responses spreadsheet, and attempting to move that will create a 'ghost' column which can't be removed. Similar issues will be encountered with removing rows etc.

If the system you are working on is anything more than trivial, Google Forms are not the way to go. But if you feel it can do what you need, then Bryan P's comment from yesterday is probably the way to go :)